# Xcode 4: How to open the currently-viewed file in the Assistant pane?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I often want to edit in two different locations in the same source file. I miss the ability to drag a vertical split in an Xcode window; this feature was apparently lost when going from Xcode 3 to 4.

Is there a super-quick way to open the currently-viewed file in the Assistant pane?

Comment: Not super quick, but you can select the Assistant logo in the Xcode "path" and manually select your currently viewed file.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that. But in projects with hundreds of files, that's no fun at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click (or control click) in the Primary editor window. A context menu should appear. In the menu there is a "Open in Assistant Editor" option. Select this and you'll have the same file in both windows.

Also in here is a "Reveal in Project Navigator" option which is useful for finding a file in a large project as you were describing.